# Google Maps API vs Multimap/Bing Maps API

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, multimap

I want to know if anyone who has experience of using both the Google Maps API ***and*** the Multimap API can give a good reason as to why one is better than the other - or maybe a list of pros and cons?

I will be working on a complete re-development of a site which currently uses the Multimap (Classic) API and want to consider the possibility of using Google Maps API instead of Multimap (now MS Bing), but I need a compelling reason to justify this decision.

The site currently provides a search mechanism allowing users to search for addresses using postcode/partial postcode or city.  The current system has a sqlserver database back-end containing full address details and also uploads (geocodes this information to Multimap with a daily scheduled task). I'm wondering if it's possible with the Google API to avoid the need for the daily upload and just use it's geocoding API instead (though this is limited by Google's restriction of a certain number of geocoding requests per day).

Answer (score 4):

In my experience using the two, Bing Maps are more accurate with regards to their geocaching, but Google have slightly nicer looking Road Maps.

The Google Maps API is slightly more helpful - for example, if you have 2 markers, the map automatically zooms out to the right level, Bing takes a bit more work.

Aerial maps look pretty much the same on both, as do the Hybrid maps.

My advice would be - use Bing maps for geocaching, then if you want really nice looking road maps, use Google. If you're using Aerial, Hybrid or Birdseye view, you might as well stick with Bing.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap.com) Multimap was purchased by Microsoft some years ago and its direction features were merged into the Microsoft Bing api. I suppose the Multimap API primarily exists for legacy purposes. By the end of 2010 multimap might disappear, so this is definitely a compelling reason to re-write the geocoding part of your app...

In any case I would contact Multimap how long they plan to support their API and if there is a migration path (probably to bing maps).

Bing Maps as well as Google Maps now offer real-time geocoding services over Javascript (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff710027.aspx for an example in bing). Which one to pick? Check the terms of usage and the costs of the geocoding requests per day.

Answer (score 1):

Yes skip the old legacy Multimap and use Google Maps or Bing Maps. Both are in active competition and under active development. So one might be better in one area for a few months but the chances are it will change. Eg. Bing Maps was the first with multi-touch support (using Silverlight) but Google Maps now supports it with its v3 API. (unfortunately all but the most basic map overlays will crash Google Maps multi-touch apps crash with the most widely available multi-touch platform:  Safari on the iPad/iPhone).

At the moment I think Bing Maps has the edge, but at the end of the day your decision is probably going to be subjective (those maps look nicer / I find the API slightly nicer / etc), or depending on the exact wording of the EULA (ie. do you pay? and how much? for your specific application).

You talked about geocoding. An increasing number of people are looking at using multiple geocoding platforms. Primarily because geocoding coverage of all the services are imperfect, but it also gives you cover if one service goes down.