# Google Maps api vs Bing Maps api 2012

Tags: google-maps-api-3, comparison, bing, bing-maps

I want to develop a map api on a webpage, but I'm not sure if I should use Google or Bing. I've already done some work with Google without considering Bing, and I'm running into some limitations when loading kml files onto the map. They likely exist with Bing as well. I've looked at other posts, but they are either too specific or outdated:

- [Google Maps API vs Multimap/Bing Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060834/google-maps-api-vs-multimap-bing-maps-api)
- [Google maps or Bing maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158815/google-maps-or-bing-maps-api)
- [Google Maps, Bing Maps, OpenStreetMaps and MapQuest limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531464/google-maps-bing-maps-openstreetmaps-and-mapquest-limitation)
- [best api for develop with maps web application google-maps vs bing-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967871/best-api-for-develop-with-maps-web-application-google-maps-vs-bing-maps)
- [Bing Maps vs Google Maps -> markers are in different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380248/bing-maps-vs-google-maps-markers-are-in-different-places)
- [Get user's location (latitude, longitude) with Bing or Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914580/get-users-location-latitude-longitude-with-bing-or-google-maps-api)
- [JavaScript UI for ideally Bing maps or Google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316667/javascript-ui-for-ideally-bing-maps-or-google-maps)

What are the pros and cons of Bing and Google maps api? Ex: download size, user-friendliness, number of features for free usage, number of maps available for download, number of searches etc. What are your experiences with either of them?

Comment: Please see: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/185112)

Comment: I'm fairly new to this forum, so just to be clear, all of the other posts that I listed also should not be posted because they ask for comparisons between products?

Comment: I'd say so. SO answers questions about specific difficulties with code [mainly]. See the top two questions in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Gavin is right , im not ganged up with him , but why some useful conversation like this closed as not constructive , otherwise atleast tell us where can we discuss things like this

Answer (score 5):

The things that I learned about the difference between Bing Maps versus Google Maps Api

1. The Google API have a better documentation
2. Google Has the [playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)
3. When you used the Geocoding, you will see that outside of united states Google maps it's more accurate than bing and more tolerant about the query request, in fact if you want to do a Geocoding with bing i'm truly recommend you to be the more specific that you can.
4. Bing maps still say `beta` on his logo

Comment: and moreover, as a developer point of view, there is no streetview in Bing

Comment: Now that it is 2017, things may have improved.  Bing Maps API is doing a nice job of correcting addresses for me.  Here are some helpful links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701704.aspx, and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx